# Rails how to index with in_groups_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am displaying pictures in a view using in_groups_of to create rows of 3.  However, I need to do something different to the first item of the first row.  How can I target this item?

```
<% images.in_groups_of(3) do |row| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% row.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
      <div class="item-wrapper">
        <% if image %>
          <a class="flex-item" <img class="photo" src="<%= image.picture.medium.url %>" alt="" /></a>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to add this code below every anchor tag except the very first photo in the very first row.

```
<% if user.eql?(current_user) %>
  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete-image" data-id="<%= image.id %>">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
  </button>            
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the index of the current row, try this:

```
<% images.in_groups_of(3).each_with_index do |row, row_index| %>
```

Now you can just check that neither `row_index` or `index` are zero, and then print the wanted code.